# what does this means 'error in Version string 'svn3799ppa1~maverick1' version number does not start with digit'?

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, gnome, partial-upgrade

'error in Version string 'svn3799ppa1~maverick1' version number does not start with digit'
this message is shown each time during the package installation in gnome3 upgrade. Why this message is coming and will this cause a errors in other programs??

Comment: Is there any more context to go with that error message?  It sounds like it is referring to a package with a weird version number, but without more info it is difficult to say any more.

Comment: this happpens after i upgrade to gnome 3 in ubuntu 11.04(upgraded from 10.10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a google search for the version number and the only reference I came up with was for [a PPA for a program called Handbrake](https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/handbrake-snapshots).  Did the part of the error message you didn't include in the question mention that package?

Assuming this is the case, it looks like the packages in this PPA had a weird naming convention.  The owner of the PPA has since changed them slightly such that it shouldn't trigger this error, but it isn't clear that the new packages would be considered newer than the old broken ones.

If that is so, I would suggest removing the `handbrake` package and seeing if that allows you to install the other updates:

```
sudo apt-get remove handbrake
```

If everything upgrades correctly after doing that, you could try installing the package again (which should hopefully give you a version without a broken version number).

Comment: `sudo apt-get install handbrake`
worked for me...